# Facebook4j getting posts limited to last 2 weeks?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

When I try to fetch all Facebook posts a user placed on his wall using a stream with Facebook4j I only seem to be able to get the posts from the last 14 days. Is there a way to circumvent this limit and get every message ever posted by the user on the wall?

I am using pagination and got 550 messages from the last 2 weeks but not further than that.

This is my code

```
private void printFBMessages(FileWriter fileWriter, String nameFeed)
        throws InterruptedException, IOException, FacebookException {
    int n = 0;
    boolean notEmpty = true;
    while (notEmpty) {
        try {
            notEmpty = false;
            System.out.println("N: " + n);
            for (Post post : facebook.getFeed(nameFeed, new Reading().limit(100).offset(n))) {
                notEmpty = true;
                MessageInfo msg = new MessageInfo();
                msg.setDate(post.getCreatedTime().toString());
                msg.setTitle(post.getMessage());
                System.out.println(msg);
                n++;

                addControleToResult(fileWriter, nameFeed, msg);
            }
            if (!notEmpty) {
                System.out.println("Empty");
            }
        } catch (FacebookException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            Thread.sleep(300000);
        }
        n++;
    }
    System.out.println("Done!");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was handling the paging wrong, and that was the reason why it didn't work as expected.

This is an example of code that actually works as expected:

```
private void printFBMessages(FileWriter fileWriter, String nameFeed)
        throws InterruptedException, IOException, FacebookException {
    boolean notEmpty = true;

    facebook4j.ResponseList<Post> posts = facebook.getFeed(nameFeed, new Reading().limit(100));

    while (notEmpty) {
        try {
            notEmpty = false;

            for (Post post : posts) {
                notEmpty = true;
                MessageInfo msg = new MessageInfo();
                msg.setDate(post.getCreatedTime().toString());
                msg.setTitle(post.getMessage());
                System.out.println(msg);

                addControleToResult(fileWriter, nameFeed, msg);
            }               
            posts = facebook.fetchNext(posts.getPaging());
        } catch (FacebookException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            Thread.sleep(300000);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done!");
    return;
}
```